# ALEXA Amazon Echo, SKILL

Tags: api, alexa-skills-kit

Is there an API that we can use to invoke the invocation name and execute an intention.
This is what I want to do is send an alert to Alexa and she speaks without having said the invocation name
Thank you, :)

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your use case. There is a Reminders API that might meet your needs. It can provide a reminder to a customer at a later time after a session has ended, but it needs to be set with the customer's approval. So your customer would have to invoke the skill and approve setting the reminder, but then the reminder could occur at a later time.

https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/alexa-reminders-api-reference.html

For example, I've played a game that only lets you take a specific action every 90 minutes. In the game, it asks if you want to set a reminder for 90 minutes later. Ninety minutes later, whether you're playing the game or not, Alexa provides the reminder.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no API like that. If you want your Alexa to speak, you have to start the conversation with voice. It's by design.

However you can try build a small device/mobile app with endpoint that could play the recorded voice ("Alexa, open my skill") and play it near Alexa.

Also you can try [Skill Invocation API](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/skill-invocation-api.html) - you will receive Alexa's response in JSON - in my opinion it's good enough for tests (since you are not testing how Alexa pronounce words in response).

Or [Skill Simulation API](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/skill-simulation-api.html).